# What causes [almost] instant missle tone/launch while flying?

Tags: battlefield-4

Several times while flying, I seem to get in the *insta-locked-on-and-missle-fired* situation.   I don't hear the locking tone (when someone is trying to lock onto me), so deploying ECM is a pain (as the missile is already sent to me).  As I perfer ECM over flares (more time to get away), but why does this instant locking/missile launched happen?   Is this a glitch?  I also tend to use the stealth perk.

Comment: It might be the igla, since you can fire it without locking and then lock on quickly to hit you while the rocket is in the air already.

Comment: or active radar missiles. Do you know what the source of the missiles are?

Answer (score 3):

Two possibilities:

- If you're getting hit very quickly after hearing the warning: **Active Radar** missiles.
- If it doesn't seem so "omg wtf" fast, then it's probably a bug with lockon weapons, where someone has been trying to lock you but you were out of their range, and then when you enter their ~350m range the lock sometimes finishes instantly.

---

If you're getting hit almost instantly, then they're Active Radar missiles, which are available for Stealth Jets and the Mobile Anti-Air.

The missiles are fired without a lock, and fly in a straight line... until a target passes close enough in front of them. Then they automatically lock and begin chasing that target.

This means that there is no "locking but not yet fired" phase, so your alert-beeper goes instantly to the highest threat level. In addition, they are often fairly close to you when they lock, so there's very little travel-time before they hit.

Answer (score 1):

As an avid anti-vehicle player, I can tell you that this form of "instant locking" that you describe only seems to happen on one occasion. When I target a vehicle from a long distance, the launcher displays a muted lock-on icon as it recognizes that there is a vehicle but it's too far away to lock-on. However, if I keep this "muted lock" on the vehicle as it gets closer to me, the launcher instantly locks on when the vehicle comes into range rather than requiring a period of waiting time.

Comment: Can please someone confirm this? I also rarely get shot without any lock signal and suddenly drop from 100 to "red health region". I suspect it has to do with SRAWs since there is no signal but SRAW alone cannot inflict that much damage. I am confused :)

Comment: I, too, have only seen this when an aircraft is locking onto me while I am in a little bird.  I've noticed also when flying an airplane the lock seems to happen quicker on helis.

Comment: @Anar If an SRAW hits either the light chopper or attack chopper it is a 1 shot, also for both jets. The only one that can survive an sraw is the transport chopper.

Comment: @Lyrion Actually I was on a transport heli, repairing it. Do you know how much damage does a single SRAW rocket inflict?

Comment: @Anar I don't know, but I do know that 2 shots is enough to take down a transport chopper. My guess is it does at around 70-80 damage

Comment: I believe SRAWS do not give a lock-on warnining unless they are being laser guided by a SOFLAM or PLD. I have taken down Little Birds with one SRAW rocket before, as well as a transport chopper, although the transport chopper could have taken some damage beforehand.